# How do I prevent <input type="submit"> from submitting my form until a criteria has been met?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, forms, jquery-validation-engine

I have a form that the user fills out, then they press a "Review Fields" button. This button validates the fields by using jQuery Validation (https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) and opens a bootstrap modal with the fields to be reviewed on it.

After the user reviews their fields in the modal, there is another "Submit Form" button at the bottom of the modal.

So, my "review fields" button has type="submit" to run the validation, but I "return false;" the button. The modal popup "submit form" button also has type="submit" for the same form, but I need to turn "return true;" back on for the form.

This is what I have:

```
// call to validate form
$( '#formEntry' ).validate();

// when modal is hidden, don't allow form submission
$( '#confirm-submit' ).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $( '#formEntry' ).submit(function() {
    return false;
  });
});

// when form is valid and submitted, open modal
$( '#submitBtn' ).click( function() {
  if ( $( '#formEntry' ).valid() ) {
    $( '#confirm-submit' ).modal();
  }
});
```

which works, but the "review" modal opens then submits within half a second, not allowing the user to actually review the fields then click the "submit" button when ready.

`#formEntry` is my form id

`#confirm-submit` is my modal id

`#submitBtn` is my "review fields" button id

Comment: You could use `<button type='button'` and handle the click event rather than the form submit event.  Just an alternative approach that might solve your issue.

Comment: I cant seem to get the jquery validation to work when I do that. I think it may require "submit" to run, but I guess I should read further in to the jquery validation documentation. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: What if you use preventDefault (); instead of the return false?
$( '#formEntry' ).submit(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });